# Visual Basic 2012 "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

```
Public Class Form1    
    Private Sub btn_calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_calculate.Click
        Dim MonthPayment As Double
        Dim LoanAmount As Double = txtbox_loan.Text
        Dim IntRate As Double = txtbox_IntRate.Text
        Dim Years As Double = txtbox_years.Text
        Dim tempI, temp1, temp2 As Double 'temporary variables'
        tempI = IntRate / 1200
        temp1 = (1 + tempI) ^ ((-12) * Years)
        temp2 = (tempI / (1 - temp1))
        MonthPayment = temp2 * LoanAmount
        txtbox_MonthPayment.Text = "$" & Math.Round(MonthPayment, 2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is what I have so far. I keep getting the error `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and it highlights LoanAmount As Double = txtbox_loan.Text , I think I need to change something with it being a string, but do not know how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you cannot assign a string to a double variable. For compatibility with old VB6 code, Visual Studio offers the option to switch off this behavior setting [Option Strict Off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) in the properties of your project.

I strongly suggest to keep `Option Strict` set to `On` because these kind of assignement, when handled by the automatic conversion enabled by `Option Strict Off`, could be very dangerous.

Getting back to you code, you need use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and write

```
Dim LoanAmount As Double
if Not double.TryParse(txtbox_loan.Text, LoanAmout) then
   .... Message for your user ....conversion not possible.. Not a valid double number ??? 
End If
```

and so on for the other numeric values that you need to convert